# JS .style.display = "inline" Will display as "inline-block" in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, inline

I am writing a code for a "Read more" button, following this example from [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp). The code basically shows and hides the longer text.

The problem I am facing is with the JS code `.style.display = "inline"`, but it's displayed as `inline-block` instead, so it moves my text into next line.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
    btnText.classList.remove("hide_me");
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Hide";
    btnText.classList.add("hide_me");
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
    
    jQuery("#more").animate({
      maxHeight: '200px',
      height: '200px'
    }, );
  }
  
  if (document.getElementById('vec').style = "inline") {
    document.getElementById("vec").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("preberiVec").innerHTML = "Preberi več";
    document.getElementById('pikice').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("preberiVec").classList.remove('skrij_me');
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="more">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when 
     an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
     </span>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="gumb_vec" id="myBtn">Read more </button></p>
```

On the link below, its shown how the text is displayed after it's clicked on read more button:

[image]

The text is displayed in new line as `inline-block`, but I would like to have it displayed as `inline` in the same line as the text before.

If anyone have dealt with this problem before, please help me out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the jQuery animate function that funks with your concept - if you remove it as per the below it works as expected (except without animation).

```js
function myFunction() {
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
        moreText.style.display = "none";
        btnText.classList.remove("hide_me");    
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Hide"; 
        btnText.classList.add("hide_me");
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
        //jQuery("#more").animate({maxHeight : '200px', height : '200px'},);
    }
}
```

```css
#more {display: none;}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
 <span id="dots">...</span>
 <span id="more">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when 
 an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
 </span>
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="gumb_vec" id="myBtn">Read more </button></p>
```

Comment: Oh you're right, I haven't noticed that.. Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: @RokPolovič if you can, use CSS animations as these won't change the display of the element.